# Is there a way to detect which side the Alt key was pressed on (right or left)?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way that we can detect which side the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key was pressed on, i.e. distinguish between left or right <kbd>Alt</kbd>? I saw somewhere that it's possible with IE with the `altLeft` and `altRight` properties of the `Event` object. If that is correct, how can we detect it in Firefox with JavaScript?

This is how it works in IE for `altLeft`:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('id').onkeydown = function(){
    alert(window.event.altLeft);
  }
}
```

Comment: In this test case there simply seems to be no difference in the event  objects when the left or right alt key is pressed, except the timestamps: http://jsfiddle.net/8gY5M/.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### 2015 answer

DOM3 added a [`location` property of keyboard events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-KeyboardEvent-location) (see also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/location)) (earlier versions had a `keyLocation` property instead) which does what you want and is implemented in recent versions of all major browsers.

Demo:

```js
document.getElementById("ta").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  var keyLocation = ["Standard", "Left", "Right", "Numpad", "Mobile", "Joystick"][e.location];
  var message = "Key '" + (e.key || e.keyIdentifier || e.keyCode) + "' is down. Location: " + keyLocation;
  this.value += "\n" + message;
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" rows="10" cols="50">Click on here and press some modifier keys such as Shift</textarea>
```

### 2011 answer

No. In general, it is impossible to distinguish between left and right modifier keys in a cross-browser way. The `shiftLeft`, `shiftRight`, `ctrlLeft`, `ctrlRight`, `altLeft`, `altRight` properties of `window.event` are all IE only and no equivalent exists in other browsers.

DOM3 added a [`location` property of keyboard events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-KeyboardEvent-location) (earlier versions had a `keyLocation` property instead) but Firefox does not implement this.

Comment: It should be noted that as of Firefox 15, the [`location` property is implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/location#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @LucienGreathouse: Thanks. I've rewritten the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Good question. The event object does not contain anything about which alt is pressed but you can try something like this:

```
var altLeft = false,
    altRight = false,
    time = null;

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    //The time check is because firefox triggers alt Right + alt Left when you press alt Right so you must skip alt Left if it comes immediatelly after alt Right
    if (e.keyCode === 18 && (time === null || ((+new Date) - time) > 50)) {
        altLeft = true;
        time = null;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 17) {
        altRight = true;
        time = + new Date;
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode === 18) altLeft = false;
    else if (e.keyCode === 17) altRight = false;
}

document.onclick = function () {
    console.log("left", altLeft, "right", altRight);
}
```

It works for me in Firefox, anyway the 17 and 18 (that are key codes for alt Right and Left) can change on different browsers or operating systems so you must check them.

Comment: If you're getting a `keyCode` other than 18 then the key you're pressing is not `Alt`. You cannot distinguish between alt keys in Firefox.

Comment: @Tim Yeah i got it 18 for both in FF 3.6.5

Comment: I have Firefox 8 and if i press Alt Left i get 18 if i press Alt Right the event is triggered twice and i get 17 and 18.

Comment: To be honest i get 17 for Ctrl too so in the click function the altKey property on the event object must be checked

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        flag = 0;
        text = ['else', 'Ctrl', 'AltGr', 'Alt'];

        function key_down(e) {
            var aa = e.keyCode;
            if (aa == 18) {
                event.keyCode = 0;
                event.returnValue = false;
            }
            this_key(aa);
        }

        function this_key(fn1) {
            if (fn1 == 17) {
                flag = 1;
                timer = setTimeout('this_key(1)', 10);
                return;
            }
            if (fn1 == 18 && flag == 1) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }

            var aa = 0;

            if (fn1 == 1) {
                aa = 1;
            }
            if (fn1 == 18) {
                if (flag == 1) {
                    aa = 2;
                } else {
                    aa = 3;
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text[aa];
            flag = 0;
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onkeydown="key_down(event);">
        <div id="result" style="font-size: 5em;"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is my solution

Comment: Would you mind explaining it? The variable names are far from self-descriptive, no comment whatsoever... The answer is not very useful if it cannot be understood.