# jQuery check for clicking left ctrl + left shift and left ctrl + right shift

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I tried to do this code:

```
$(input).keyup(function (e)
{
    alert(e.shiftKey);
});
```

But every character that I write shows "false", how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking. If you're asking about distinguishing between left and right modifier keys (shift, ctrl, alt etc.) then it's not generally possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8562791/96100

Comment: I want to do this code: if ( left shift + left alt) { ... }

Comment: In which event? Are any other keys pressed? As I mentioned, you won't generally be able to distinguish between left and right shift or alt.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly this is not possible with the event API — both shift keys return keyCode 16, both ctrl keys return 17 — they're indistinguishable!

Sorry for the bad news :(

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is using `keyup()`. By the time the event fires the shift key was released and is not more active. Try using `keydown()` or `keypress()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("input").keydown(function (e)
{
    if(e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey){ alert("shift + crtl Pressed");}
});
```

this works fine

Comment: It works, but I don't want alt, I want ctrl.

Answer (score 0):

The follow will be triggered while both keys are down:

```
$(input).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey) {
        // This code would run if both the control and shift are down.
    }
});
```

However, it will continue to be triggered for as long as they are down, see the jQuery [example](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/#example-0) by holding down both keys in the input box.

I thought jQuery's [.keypress()](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/#example-0) would be able to let you know when they were pressed rather than just held, but it appears that it only gets called on character keys `a-z, 0-1, ?!>~#`, etc.

Comment: It doesn't work: if (e.shiftKey && e.ctrlKey)

Comment: @user1123379: It works perfectly. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/bRtZH/2/

Comment: @KillerX, your jsfiddle is using `alt` not `shift` and `ctrl`.

Comment: @user1123379 see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U9E6S/) for an example of it in practice.

Comment: @ThomasNadin Eh, saved the wrong version :)