# Detect Alt Gr (Alt Graph) modifier on key press

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, keyboard

In the javascript `Event` object, there are some boolean values to check if modifier keys are pressed:

- `ctrlKey`: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key.
- `altKey`: <kbd>ALT</kbd> key.
- `altLeft`: <kbd>ALT</kbd> left key. Only for IE.
- `altGraphKey`: <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> key. Only for Chrome/Safari.

However, there are some issues:

- IE and Chrome set `ctrlKey` to `true` and `altKey` to `true` when you press the ALTGR modifier.
- Firefox sets `ctrlKey` to `false` and `altKey` to `true` when you press the ALTGR modifier, as only ALT has been pressed.
- Chrome has the `altGraphKey` property, but it is always `undefined`.

Question: how can I difference between an <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd> or an <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> key press? Specially in Chrome.

Comment: Current browser behaviour (September 2013) is different. See the answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The altGraphKey in webkit browsers no longer appears to exist (as at September 2013) and the behaviour of Firefox has changed. Browser behaviours for the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key currently appear to be:

- Webkit (Chrome) - ctrlKey: true, altKey: true
- IE 8 - ctrlKey: false, altKey: true
- IE 10 - ctrlKey: true, altKey: true
- Mozilla (Firefox) - ctrlKey: true, altKey: true

Which is to say, they are all currently consistent (apart from IE8, which remains consistently inconsistent).

The following snippet should catch <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> - but not <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - in modern browsers. You will need a special case for IE8 however:

```
if (event.ctrlKey && event.altKey) {
    // Appears to be Alt Gr
}
```

Comment: Pressing CTRL+ALT+S is *not* the same as pressing ALTGR+S. Am using an US-Int keyboard layout and I just had an issue where I wanted to type a German ß character with visual studio code (Electron based). And instead of an ß character I get the "run task" menu (shortcut CTRL+ALT+S) jumping at me. In my opinion this is a bug.

Comment: The very same thing happens when you press AltGr+Q on a German keyboard. It should emit the @ character, but instead the CTRL+ALT+Q JavaScript keyboard shortcut handler gets notified. What's intriguing is that I can only reproduce this on Windows - in Linux the @ character is emitted properly. I also think this is a bug, however on Windows the behavior is consistent on Edge, Firefox and Chrome? I'm quite confused...

Comment: Nightmare on Android, where the same problem now makes VSCode via web browser largely unusable for international users. When inspecting the information sent when pressing AltGr and 8, meaning [, then the ctrlKey and altKey bools get true, yet the key (code?) actually is [ instead of 8. Still causes mayhem in Electron/VSCode as this isn't taken as a plain [ due to the set Ctrl and Alt keys.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I don't have a keyboard that has this key, so I can't test myself, but the spec says that can use the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) property. This may be a good solution if you only need to support browsers that implement it (at time of writing, only Safari doesn't). You can check if the value is [`"AltGraph"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values).

```js
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
  if (e.key === 'AltGraph') {
    console.log(e.key);
  }
};
```

Comment: @zuluk Thanks for the notification. Can you confirm if it works in any other browsers?

Comment: @zuluk That's interesting. I wonder if any of the [other values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values) work for you?

Comment: This answer works perfectly with Chrome 67 under Windows 10 both with physical and on-screen keyboard. Also differentiates between AltGr and Ctrl+Alt so it's my preferred solution for Chrome. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50341#issuecomment-399053187
Firefox and Edge still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> key and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> key combo are the same thing and there is no way to make a difference in Javascript.
Pressing <kbd>ALTGR</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> are both producing the € (euro) symbol on my keyboard/language setup.
There are pages online to check keycodes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this was a Google Chrome bug, in Canary it works ok, in Opera and Firefox - too. Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/iegik/PpH76/

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning is that it is possible to detect this in modern browser by checking the location of the alt key event.

See: [Is there a way to detect which side the Alt key was pressed on (right or left)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562528/is-there-is-a-way-to-detect-which-side-the-alt-key-is-pressed)