# How can I detect if left Alt + letter was pressed

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events

I need to perform some action only if the left <kbd>ALT</kbd> key was pressed with the letter <kbd>s</kbd>.
I can find whether some <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> pressed using the `keydown` event, when `oEvent.altKey === true` and `String.fromCharCode(oEvent.keyCode) === 'S'`.
I can also find whether the left or right <kbd>ALT</kbd> was pressed by:

```
oEvent.originalEvent.location === KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT
```

or

```
oEvent.originalEvent.location === KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT
```

But what I could not find is the way to combine the two.

Comment: the question is not understandable. do you not have the solution in there?

Comment: No. I can detect Some ALT + 's' (left ALT or right ALT), I can distinguish between left and right ALT but WITHOUT any letter, but I didn't find a way to detect when I click only on the left ALT key + the letter 's' (or any other letter)

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562528/is-there-is-a-way-to-detect-which-side-the-alt-key-is-pressed)

Comment: Thanks, but I already read it. As you can see in my question I can distinguish between right/left ALT key, but not if you add another letter afterwards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For make this you have to register two events, `keyUp` and `keyDown` and using a single variable can do the trick,

```
 isleftAltPressed : false,

keyUp: function(e)
{
  var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if(keyCode == 18)
      isleftAltPressed = false;
},

keyDown: function(e)
{
  var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode;

  if(keyCode == 18 && e.originalEvent.location === KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT)
      isleftAltPressed = true;

    if(e.altKey && isleftAltPressed && keyCode == 83)
      alert("hi");

},
```

Comment: @MarkRobbins no it does not works with tab key (on Windows OS) I think  system is handling the event on top, might work in IOS (Apple) as Alt key is flipped with windows key in normal keyboard